# SELECT * FROM name WHERE surname LIKE 'james, boot';

Tags: sql, mariadb

I just want to select a table and show all names where the surname are like 2 that are the same.

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE surname LIKE 'james, boot';
```

**Problem :** I cant display all the names ***WHERE*** surname are ***LIKE*** "James" and "Noah"

Comment: you can use `or` and wildcard

Comment: Why use `LIKE` here?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the expected result

Comment: @Ajay Gupta, He solved my problem. Sorry for structuring the question wrong. I have no idea why i use `LIKE`. When i tried to solve my problem i googled and found an example that almost worked and it had `LIKE` in

Comment: Still after 2 days can't really understand the question.

Answer (score 4):

You won't need `like` here.

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE surname IN ('james', 'boot');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE surname LIKE '%James%' or surname LIKE '%Noah%';
```

Comment: Why use LIKE and not have a wildcard anywhere

Comment: Still no [wildcard](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) after your update.

Comment: I did not see structure of table, I am thinking OP has column surname which consists only surname

Comment: Ok. I added wildcard to start and end of surnames

Comment: @Sakezzz I have one Table with ID,NAME, Surname, TIME. And i want to display all the names where there surnames are the same. Sorry im new to SQL query's

Comment: Did you try my query?